# DateTime.parseExact no funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quiero validar si un string es una fecha, el string lo traigo de una conexión con una API y viene de la siguiente manera

20181025

```
public static Boolean IsDate(string Expression)
    {
        Boolean resultado = false;
        try
        {
            DateTime isDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Expression, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
            resultado = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            resultado = false;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

pero aun usando el DateTime no logro parsearlo y la funcion me devuelve false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El formato que tratas de de introducir para el valor 20181025 es "yyyyMMdd", pero estas definiendo usar el formato  "dd/MM/yyyy", lo cual es incorrecto:

```
  DateTime isDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Expression, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

si deseas usar el formato "yyyyMMdd", debes definirlo para el método [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) :

```
  DateTime isDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Expression, "yyyyMMdd", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

La fecha es 20181025 no coincide con el formato que estás indicando en `DateTime.ParseExact`, en lugar de `"dd/MM/yyyy"` prueba con `"yyyyMMdd"`.